# How can a Android client receive GCM message?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Follow the guid in [gcm quick start](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start), I successfully configure the **GCM** demo, and I can get the push message from the server(**GcmSender.java**). From the structure of the project "app", I can see 5 class:

**MainActivity.java**

**MyGcmListenerService.java**

**MyInstanceIDListenerService.java**

**QuickstartPreferences.java**

**RegistrationIntentService.java**

But I can not find where the client build the **TCP** connection with the **GCM server**, therefore I do not understand why the client can receive the **GCM** message?

Comment: GCM relies on Google Play Services. Google maintains the persistent connections to devices through that, which lives in another process on the device. That process received the push message and federates it to the proper app. Hence your app does not need to build any connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to worry about **TCP** connection because that is handled by GCM server , Our Application Server and Google Play Services

We recive message because we have [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

See below explanation

**Push notifications** let your application notify a user of new messages or events even when the user is not actively using your application. On Android devices, when a device receives a `push notification`, your application's icon and a message appear in the status bar.

See [this tutorial for complete GCM tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Does that mean when GCM server send a message to my app, the google play service receive first and then it send a broadcast to let my app receive it?

Comment: yes . Then your `BrodcastReciver` will catch that and you can do what you want to do in `OnRecive` method